# Using converters for DataGrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I create my windows databainding infrastructure with MVVM pattern. I have method which return data for my DataGrid. **Problem that  I want some columns in DataGrid use Converter (IValueConverter) but I bind my DataGrid to the data directly.** I can't strongly type columns specification in xaml because number of columns can be different. Also I can't get UI element (DataGrid) in ViewModel for change.

Comment: You mean you auto-generating columns?

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel can expose the column collection (structure which can specify column header, type of data, necessary information to use converter) bind that to a DP of your view and your view needs to add the columns to the datagrid after parsing that and preparing datatemplate for datagrid column's cell template and cell edittemplate which specifies the binding source, converter.